# Old Investment in bankrupt company

Tags: stocks

I invested in Adelphia in 2005. In 2006, the company sunk and was sold off to Time-Warner. I recently contacted TDA to see if I could clean things up a bit and I was told that the shares are in escrow and they couldn't remove them without authorization from Adelphia. I remember the preferred stock share holders were supposed to receive shares from Time Warner. My question: is there anything I can do to recover anything from what I wrote off already as a total loss?

Comment: Are you sure you have _preferred_ shares? Did you make that clear when contacting TDA?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were common stock, but why in escrow? Is there a value?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the preferred shares to receive shares from Time Warner, they would have had to have been convertible preferred stocks, of which Adelphia had two (ADLM and ADLP).  The prospectuses are avaliable at the SEC.gov .  If you owned the common then this is of no relevance to you - the M&A terms would be have been applicable.

If you have a book entry of "worthless" shares at TDA then TDA is the one who should be helping you to resolve this issue. Brokers have a procedure for which can declare near worthless Pink Sheet shares worthless and deleting the book  entry from your account.  Telling you to contact Adelphia (which may be long gone into the ether) is most likely a wild goose chase.

I have no clue if any of this info is relevant or useful.  Try badgering someone else at TDA :->)

Comment: http://www.adelphiarestructuring.com seems to have lots of information about exactly which preferreds got what.  Wrapped in hundreds of pages of legal documents of course.  Adelphia Recovery Trusts still trade on OTC today (ADAPL, ADPAA, ADPAJ, ADPAK, ADPAS, ADPBK), but at sub-penny levels.  They have paid out some sub-penny distributions over the years, but it's chump change.